# I can't edit a credit card information in PayPal Sandbox

Tags: paypal, sandbox

I'm trying to follow steps in this official documentation:
https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/express-checkout/ht_ec_fundingfailure10486/

After near 6 hours of research, I finally managed to create an account from developer.paypal.com that could be accessible from sandbox.paypal.com. Since all changes were made to the developers side, testing is more than a pain and it's harder than before, when it was not easy either.

Well, so I'm now logged into my sandbox.paypal.com account and I want to edit my credit card address as pointed in the tutorial:

> Replace the contents of the street address Line-1 of the buyer's test credit card, with CCREJECT-REFUSED.

When I click on the "Edit" card link, inside my profile in PayPal's Sandbox page, all I get is a blank page.

Does anyone have a workaround for this bug? Thank you.

Comment: not enough info. is this blank page coming from YOUR server? or paypals?

Comment: I'm on PayPal's sandbox page. If you try to edit your credit card address in your PayPal's Sandbox account, are you receiving this blank page too?

Comment: What kind of account type are you using? I tried to modify the credit card address for a US Business account and I was able to edit the address and save the changes successfully.

Comment: I had a Personal US account. It's working with a US Business one so I suppose that I'll have to do tests with that account. Thank you, PayPal_Patrick.